# How to preserve custom .bst format, but prevent loss of capitalization?

Tags: bibtex

I have the following code in a custom .bst file:

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { "t" change.case$ }
  if$
  "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "\enquote{" swap$ *
      "}, " *
    }
  if$
}
```

I would like to keep everything the same, EXCEPT, I want it to leave the capitalization alone.

Bit of background: I use Zotero and Better Bibtex. All files in Zotero are tagged with #LaTeX which forces Zotero to leave the title AS WRITTEN--so I can use LaTeX formatting in the title. Unfortunately, this also keeps it from adding curly braces where capitals exist, so now bibtex gives me lowercase everywhere (but at least does the LaTeX formatting correctly!).

If only bibtex will leave the caps alone, I'll be a happy camper.

Thank you.

Comment: I can never be sure with the `.bst` language without testing myself, but you will probably want to look into removing the block `duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { "t" change.case$ }
  if$` (I think it would be enough to remove the whole block, but I might be wrong...).

Comment: wow, good call. Not knowing the language I was just cutting parts out with amusing results, but this did it immediately. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"t" change.case$` changes the case of `title` to sentence case (only the first letter is left alone, everything else that is not brace-protected is converted to lowercase). You want to get rid of the whole block containing this call. Your function will then read

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
  "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    {
      "\enquote{" swap$ *
      "}, " *
    }
  if$
}
```